# Ubuntu 20.04 in Hyper-V Enhanced Mode

Tags: grub2, hyper-v

I have a 19.10 Virtual Machine wich runs in Enhanced Mode, i.e. Full Screen, Shared Folders etc.  However I have done a Quick Create of a 20.04 installation and the Gnu Grub screen does not bring up the options box to enable these options - Enhanced Mode is greyed out on the toolbar.

What am I doing wrong or what can I do to fix this?

(I will continue to try to upgrade my 19.10 version but it keeps bombing out on me!)

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for reaching out for help. Could you clarify the os you are running hyperv on and whether your issues are just hyperv, just ubuntu, or a combination of both.

Comment: Thank you for responding - I have solved the problem by following: https://medium.com/@labappengineering/ubuntu-20-04-on-hyper-v-8888fe3ced64

Comment: Congratulations, in that case would you consider writeing up an answer to your question? External resources can change making your comment less helpful over time. As little as just the basic outline of the steps may help if the current content pointed to by the link is lost.

Comment: Note that there is a PR for an update to install.sh at https://github.com/microsoft/linux-vm-tools/pull/106, and also that the script and the medium link steps will NOT work with the April 23, 2020 Hyper-V Quick Create image but seem to work fine if you install from an ISO.

Comment: Got it working short term by using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hinara/linux-vm-tools/ubuntu20-04/ubuntu/20.04/install.sh

Comment: You expected the Quick Create to function correctly OOB?!! From posted GitHub it worked better on ISO install than Quick Create, if anything they released a worse version of the image. I deleted it after my HDD filled up in 10 minutes, wasn't worth expanding rather do fresh manual install w ISO.